# List function help and trying to simulate from a multivarate normal mixture in R

Tags: r, list, simulation, normal-distribution

I am trying to generate data from a mixture of two bivariate normals with the following set-up:

```
library(MASS)

 N <- 500 #sample size
 components <- c(1,2)

 mu1 <- c(0,0)
 mu2 <- c(4,4)
 mu <- list(mu1,mu2)
 var1 <- cbind(c(1,0),c(0,1))
 var2 <- cbind(c(.5,-.35),c(-.35,.5))
 var <- list(var1,var2)

 pi <- c(.33,.67) #mixing probabilities

 z <- sample(components,prob=pi,size=N,replace=TRUE)
```

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
 y <- mvrnorm(n=N,mu=mu[z],Sigma=var[z])
```

I was hoping it work analogously to generating in a mixture of univariate normals like

```
 y <- rnorm(n=N,mean=true.mu[z],sd=true.sd[z])
```

where the true.mu and true.sd were just each vectors of length 2 specifying the means and sd's. Why doesn't this work in the bivariate case? I am relatively new to the intricacies of handling lists.

In the mean time, I was generating my data in two different ways. As a list:

```
 for (i in 1:N) {
 if (z[i]==1){y[[i]] <- mvrnorm(1,mu[[1]],var[[1]])}
 else {y[[i]] <- mvrnorm(1,mu[[2]],var[[2]])}
 }
```

or as a matrix:

```
 for (i in 1:N){
 if (z[i]==1){y <- rbind(y,mvrnorm(1,mu[[1]],var[[1]]))}  
 else {y <- rbind(y,mvrnorm(1,mu[[2]],var[[2]]))}
 }
```

In sum, my questions are:

1) Why does my first method (avoiding the for loop) not work? Is there a way I can generate such data in that manner?

2) For my two for loop methods, is one better or preferred? I am going to try writing code for an EM algorithm later--is a list or a matrix easier/better to work with?

I appreciate any help! I'm trying to become more sensitive to writing things "nicely" in R :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `mvrnorm` isn't vectorised like `rnorm` is, probably because its vector and matrix (rather than scalar) arguments would make this difficult. You can use `mapply` though.

```
y <- mapply(mvrnorm, n=N, mu=mu, Sigma=var)
```

---

For your second question: building a matrix by accumulating `rbind`s can be very slow in R.

Instead you would be better off preallocating a matrix with `y <- matrix(0, 1000, 2)` and then populating the rows with `y[i,]<-`.